# MS ACCESS ADD NEW RECORD BUTTON Clears the subform data sheets

Tags: ms-access

[image]

Hi good people,

I am new to MS ACCESS and I'm doing a self study, I created this simple form and table to list down our IP Phones in our office and as we can see I have four buttons ADD DEVICE|SAVE DEVICE|DELETE DEVICE|FIND NEXT and FIND PREVIOUS. Now my problem is everytime I click the ADD DEVICE button it clears also the subform table on the right side, what I would like to achieve is when I click the add button it will only clear the textfields and leave the subform as it is. the subform will only shows every entries that I made on the text fields after I click the save button.

Comment: Is this a split form or a sub form?  
If it's a sub form linked with the parent then by default if you have no parent record there will be no child record in the sub-form.

Comment: like minty said, you can remove the "link master fields" /child fields from the subform property. or make your main form as split form.

Comment: Use split form, since that is what you are trying to emulate. Otherwise, remove the Master/Child links and use code to refresh the subform after every new record added.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out. It works like charm  ^_^